# Connecting the editor to Laravel

Tags: laravel

There is an article editor, which I understand is made for Laravel Nova.

I don't have Laravel Nova. Will I be able to use this editor without Laravel Nova and what changes do I need to make?

EditorJS in GitHub https://github.com/advoor/nova-editor-js

Comment: That specific package looks to be Nova-specific. There's no reason you couldn't do your own integration work to add Editor.js to a non-Nova site, though.

Comment: Can I just connect this code from GitHub and it will work as well?

Comment: No, but you can follow the installation and usage instructions for https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js.